# Netmiko connecting to 100 devices asynchronously

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, parallel-processing, background-process, netmiko

Is it possible to connect over 100 devices asynchronously using netmiko.
Noticed, Few examples illustrating with threads . Since the device count is quite high, is it effective to achieve async connection with threads. What else is the best alternative way.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can definitely connect using Netmiko and threads. This isn't really a problem since there is a very large amount of waiting for IO (in other words, the GIL is really not an issue here).

How many threads you can use at one time depends on a set of factors. I would expect you could use 100 without problems given my past experience.

Other solutions would be Multiprocessing or asyncio. You can't do asyncio with Netmiko since it is not async and would block.

Here is an example solution using concurrent futures and multiprocessing. The thread code would be almost identical except you would switch to ThreadPoolExecutor.

https://github.com/ktbyers/pyplus_course/blob/master/class10/collateral/CF_PROCESSES/ssh_procs_wait.py

You would need to increase the number threads in the thread/process pool i.e. max_threads (which is a misnomer in the shown code since right now it is using multiple processes).